# Unity webgl Facebook canvas app loses focus when using login dialog

Tags: facebook, iframe, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

My iframe application on Facebook (made with Unity webgl) loses focus after calling Facebook Login dialog ([FB.LogInWithReadPermissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogInWithReadPermissions)), or any other interaction with Facebook which brings up dialog window ([FB.AppRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.AppRequest) etc).

Focus is not returned to the application, so you need to click anywhere on the iframe to see the results, which is not very convenient.

Any workaround?

Edit:

Quick and dirty solution, but it works:

```
setInterval (
    function () {
        if (!document.hasFocus()) {
            window.focus();
        }
    },
    1000
);
```

Actually `document.hasFocus()` check is not needed here.

I don't think there is a way to know when Facebook dialog window closes while using Facebok Unity SDK, since the callback is executed in WebGL application which lost focus, so it doesn't work until it actually gains focus.

Maybe it's better to use Facebook Javascript SDK for Unity WebGL games on Facebook?

Comment: thanks,your solution was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue quite some time ago. I solved it by adding one listener function to index.html. It would listen if the iframe lost focus and hard reset the focus on  it. [Have a look at onblur event.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur)

Comment: Thanks, came up with a temporary solution using [document.hasFocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus), edited the question.

Comment: Also when I close Facebook dialog window, `onblur` doesn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It worked 4 me on unity 5.2 using this: 
on c# at the facebook callback:

```
 Application.ExternalCall("recuperaFocus");
```

and on the html serving the facebook canvas the next js:

```
 function recuperaFocus(){
      this.focus();      
 }
```